# Trouble completing this jQuery .slideUp code

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

Okay, first and foremost I'm a newbie to jQuery (my background is purely HTML5 / CSS3 and graphics). Anyways, I'm working on a jQuery menu (trying to learn at the same time) that opens and closes like an accordion.

I've got the first part of the menu working. When someone clicks on a top-level link with sub-menus it assigns a 'top-level-active' class to the parent li (list item) and then it uses the .slideDown function and opens the sub-menu.

Now, in order for the sub-menu to close I need to complete the '.slideUp' portion, but somehow I'm seemingly stuck on the code. This is what I have so far, but my syntax is far from correct I fear...

https://jsfiddle.net/digitalsky/undjdrg8/9/

```
function accordion_menus(){

// if we are not on mobile (menu icon is hidden) show sub items and bail
if ( jQuery('#primary-navigation .menu-toggle').is(':hidden') ){
// show sub menus
jQuery('#primary-navigation ul.nav-menu ul.sub-menu').show();
return;
} else{
// hide sub menus
jQuery('#primary-navigation ul.nav-menu ul.sub-menu').hide();
}

// top level nav click function
jQuery('#primary-navigation ul.nav-menu > li > a').click(function(e){

// store parent li to variable
var parent_li = jQuery(this).parent('li');

// if sub menu does not exist in parent li
if ( !jQuery('ul.sub-menu', parent_li).first().length ) {
    return;
}

// if sub menu is already active, bail
if ( parent_li.hasClass('sub-menu-active') ){
    return;
}

// stop link click
e.preventDefault();

// store current sub menu in variable
var current_submenu = jQuery('ul.sub-menu', parent_li).first();

// slide up non-current sub menus
jQuery('#primary-navigation ul.nav-menu > li > ul.sub-menu').not(current_submenu).slideUp(function(){

    // remove sub-menu-active class from all first level items except current parent li
    jQuery('#primary-navigation ul.nav-menu > li').not(parent_li).removeClass('sub-menu-active');

});

// slide down current sub menu
current_submenu.slideDown(100, function(){
    // add sub-menu-active to current parent li
    parent_li.addClass('sub-menu-active');
});

});

// second level nav click function
jQuery('#primary-navigation ul.nav-menu ul.sub-menu > li > a').click(function(e){

// store parent li to variable
var parent_li = jQuery(this).parent('li');

// if sub menu does not exist in parent li
if ( !jQuery('ul.sub-menu', parent_li).first().length ) {
    return;
}

// if sub menu is already active, bail
if ( parent_li.hasClass('sub-menu-active') ){
    return;
}

// stop link click
e.preventDefault();

// store current sub menu in variable
var current_submenu = jQuery('ul.sub-menu', parent_li).first();

// slide up non-current sub menus
jQuery('#primary-navigation ul.nav-menu ul.sub-menu > li > ul.sub-menu').not(current_submenu).slideUp(function(){

    // remove sub-menu-active class from all second level items except current parent li
    jQuery('#primary-navigation ul.nav-menu ul.sub-menu > li').not(parent_li).removeClass('sub-menu-active');

});

// slide down current sub menu
current_submenu.slideDown(100, function(){
    // add sub-menu-active to current parent li
    parent_li.addClass('sub-menu-active');
});

});

}
```

Long story short, I simply want the 'Course Schedule' link to open the sub-menu when you click it (which it currently does), but also close the sub-menu when you click it again.

I'm going over and over this in my head and it seems simple, but I must be over-complicating it.

Maybe I'm way off track here, but I'm learning as I go.

Comment: Can include `html` ? , create stacksnippets , http:;//jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ? Which portion of `js` is not returning expected results ?

Comment: I'll make a JS fiddle. It all works great except for the portion of the code at the bottom where it is supposed to '.slideUp'. That part doesn't work. The menu opens just fine, but when you click it again nothing happens (when it should slide back up).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your js only knows the current state of the dom when it runs.

this means that when this code is run, it does not see any parent  with the class sub-menu-active as this class is not set at the time.

It will never actually run the code that you want inside the click function since it is not attaching the click event listener to the future  element.

To fix this problem, you need to create a function that checks what you want and then set the .click(function.... inside that function.

EG...

```
function checkSlideUp(){
if ( parent_li.hasClass('sub-menu-active') ){
    jQuery('#primary-navigation ul.nav-menu > li > a').off('click').on('click', function(e){

// store parent li to variable
var parent_li = jQuery(this).parent('li');

// store current sub menu in variable
var current_submenu = jQuery('ul.sub-menu', parent_li).first();

    // slide up current sub menu
    current_submenu.slideUp(function(){
        // remove sub-menu-active to current parent li
        parent_li.removeClass('sub-menu-active');


    });
});
}
}
```

If you call checkSlideUp(); after you add the sub-menu-active class (in your other function), this will check the dom again to see if it needs to be applied at that moment.

Comment: Logically this makes sense, thank you very much! I was doing it all wrong and didn't even realize it. However, adding this code to my existing code (I updated the original post with both my code and your code), the .slideDown function for the menus works great, but the .slideUp code I added of yours doesn't cause them to slide back up on click (of the parent li).

Perhaps I'm still doing something wrong here?

Comment: If you want to see why something is not working, you should put a debug line in the code, console.log("some text" + $orSomeVariable); This way you can see what parts of the function are triggering and which are not.

Comment: @DigitalSky here is a basic JSFiddle for you https://jsfiddle.net/qo0u63zq/1/  this uses the slideup/down in a function which is called each time there is a click.

Comment: check this out, I made a fiddle so you can see the issue I'm having: https://jsfiddle.net/digitalsky/undjdrg8/9/

When I insert your code after the original '.slideDown' function it doesn't work. Play around with my fiddle there. You'll see if you click on 'Course Schedule' it opens up the drop down just fine. However, when you click on it again, it doesn't close it (even when I use your code).

This seems like it should be really simple, but I think I'm over complicating it somehow.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/undjdrg8/10/   your problem was when you had this: // if sub menu is already active, bail. At this point you needed to remove the class from the parent li.

Comment: Is it just me, or do you notice that the menus on my dev site are acting wonky using this code? http://devwww.interfacett.com. On a mobile device when you open one of the sub menus and then scroll it automatically closes it.

Comment: It is no just you. I went to your dev site on my computer and it works just fine. It also works fine when you reduce the width of the page to < 1024 px wide.  It even works fine when you use a mobile emulator in chrome. It does seem to have a problem when I view the site on my mobile. Off the top of my head I would think it has something to do with the tap being converted to a click by the web browser and not doing so well. Though not exactly sure of what the solution would be